# how get Notification ( or Just highlight the Text ) while update on ServerSide in Android?

Tags: android, listview, highlighting

I have One `ListView` I fillup data in the `listview` by `Arraylist` it comes from `web Service` ( it comes from `Serverside`)

I want to do that if any Update is done so this Update is **highlight** in the `Listview` by changing `TextColor` or Something like that

for Example : Currently there is 10 Item in the `Listview` and 4 new Item is updated from Server so **Item 1 - 10 display normal and 11-14 display in Different Color** or **Display small img near Text something like that**

you can see my Code in this [URL](http://notificationandroid.blogspot.com/2011/06/notificationandroid.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you received update information from server, call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), which will recreate the view in the list so getView() method in List_BaseAdapter will be called where you can add your text format stuff based on position.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: thanks for replay, but still i m confuse , how to know which position is update,i writh this method:public void  notifyDataSetChanged(){
        System.out.println("notify dataset is call ");
    } but this is every time call

Comment: You should not override the notifyDataSetChnged(), you need call this method when received the server update. to know more watch this video http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html